# IE11 on WIN 8.1 : window.open with the same name is opening new popup window

Tags: javascript, window.open, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

When running the below HTML page it is opening two popup windows. It is not the case with previous versions of IE. When window.open call is made with the same window name that has already opened, it should return the reference to the opened window. But in IE11 it is opening another new window.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open("http://www.google.com", "test", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
window.open("http://www.google.com", "test", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

This behavior is not happening, if you not mentioned a url. (See below html page). Below html page is launching only one popup window.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open("", "test", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
window.open("", "test", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

When we provide url or navigate to url window is losing its name. If you try to get the popup window name using window.name it is returning empty string.

It is happening only in Windows 8.1 and IE 11 and not happening in Windows 7 and IE11. 
Are there any tweaks I need to do to make this work in IE11?

**Update:**
It seems to be IE bug. IE team is investigating it.
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797964/ie11-win-8-1-window-open-with-the-same-name-is-opening-new-popup-window#details

**Update 2:**
It is happening only if Internet Explorer runs in elevated mode.

Comment: Look at settings. Perhaps there is one saying "Always open new windows in new tab"

Comment: Hi mplungjan, If I select that setting, then window.open call opening it in new tab, But I want it to be opened in new window.

Comment: I meant: UNCHECK that if it is checked

Comment: The "CONNECT" bug you cited in your update implies that you're crossing URLMon security zones, so you lose the reference to the window. Your code SHOULD work if the original page and the popup window are in the same security zone.

Comment: @EricLaw, other browser doesn't have this problem. Why is IE always doing something different???

Comment: @GrantZhu: I can't tell if that's a real question or just a complaint. IE is the only browser that is performs process isolation by security zone.

Comment: @EricLaw, just a complaint. Thanks for confirming IE is the only different one.

Comment: @Suresh what do you really mean by this - "It is happening only if Internet Explorer runs in elevated mode" you mean running IE with enhanced security option?

Comment: @Gandhi No, I mean when you run Internet Explorer as Admin

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.. this will check the window is still open or closed..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myWindow = null;

 if(!myWindow || (myWindow && myWindow.closed)){
 myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "test", "resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,width=260,height=225");
          }
         else{
       myWindow.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       }

</script>
```